# Bluetooth not working correctly - cannot browse cel. phone

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth, phone

Another issue I found in Ubuntu 11.10 - bluetooth works improperly: I cannot browse the files on my cellular phone.

in /var/syslog I see:

```
Laptop obex-data-server: sdp_extract_seqtype: Unexpected end of packet
```

However, I can send files to the phone and from the phone.

Comment: This might possibly be a [bug reported on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/obexd/+bug/879923) . This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).